# Expression resolver and condition builder

Tags: java

I have multiple expression like

```
c1|<|5&&c2|>=|750&&c3|=|1
c1|<|5&&(c2|>=|750||c3|=|1)
c1|<|5&&(c2|>=|750||c3|=|1)&&c4|=|1
c1|<|5&&c2|>=|750||c3|=|1&&c4|=|1
(c1|<|5||c2|>=|750||c3|=|1)&&c4|=|1
```

Now what I want to do here is basically I want to parse the expression and using interfaces for && and || I want to build the condition builder which basically takes the condition and then evaluate the final expression. Is there is any in Java without using any external library and using Java oops concepts where

```
c1|<|5&&c2|>=|750&&c3|=|1 -> (c1|<|5) && (c2|>=|750) && (c3|=|1)

c1|<|5&&(c2|>=|750||c3|=|1) -> (c1|<|5) && ((c2|>=|750) || (c3|=|1))

c1|<|5&&(c2|>=|750||c3|=|1)&&c4|=|1 -> (c1|<|5) && ((c2|>=|750) || (c3|=|1)) || (c4|=|1)
```

Any help would be really helpful.

Comment: why not use already existing library? creating your own binary tree system could be painful...

Comment: @AsierAranbarri I have a requirement where I won't be able use existing library and have to write some of our own.

Comment: You'll want a list of tokens (which you'll get from your string), a family of types representing syntax nodes (that preferably know how to evaluate themselves), and specs for operator precedence and associativity. From there, you can use the shunting yard algorithm to turn your list of tokens into an AST. Evaluate the root to evaluate the expression. Every one of those subproblems is still too broad to make a good SO question, though.